# Prolog decimal number to list of numbers

Tags: prolog

I am new to this page, but hopefully, I'll get the help that I need. I need to code a program that gives a list of numbers from 0-9 from a given bigger number. I don't know how to explain it better, so I add the example:

```
numbertolist(Number,List).

?- numbertolist(1456,List).

List = [1,4,5,6].
```

The main thing, that I can't use `number_chars/2`, `number_codes/2` functions, which would give this result easily, I should implement all the functions.

```
number_codes(123456,X), maplist(plus(48),Y,X).
```

gives

```
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: It's a common programming puzzle; remember your long division: `10` goes into `1456` 145 times with 6 remainder. It's no coincidence that 6 was the last digit. And 145 is a shorter number.

Comment: I see. So it basically needs to program that 1456/10, 145 + 6 remainder goes to the List = _ _ _ 6, therefore, it moves on and 145/10, 14 + 5 remainder goes to the List = _, _, 5, 6 and again? Thank you.

Comment: Accept my solution, think we will both get some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without calling `number_codes/2` is straight
forward, using the accumulator programming pattern:

```
number_digits(N, L) :-
   number_digits(N, [], L).

number_digits(0, L, L) :- !.
number_digits(N, L, R) :-
   D is N rem 10,
   M is N // 10,
   number_digits(M, [D|L], R).
```

The Prolog program gives:

```
?- number_digits(1454, X).
X = [1, 4, 5, 4].
```